# ansible extract without first directory

Tags: tar, ansible

When extracting a tar.gz file in ansible I end up with a first directory

```
- name: Extract archive
  unarchive: src=file.tar.gz
             dest=/foo/bar
```

which results in `/foo/bar/bar-version-someFirstLevelFolder/contentOfArchive`
How can I prevent creating this extra level of hierarchy?

Comment: May not be relevant but I know you sometimes need to be careful in adding a trailing slash to the destination directory.  Does that help at all?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In order to strip the `bar-version-someFirstLevelFolder` you need to use the `--strip-components=1` option in `tar`. So your playbook should look like

```
- name: Extract archive
  unarchive:
    src: file.tar.gz
    dest: /foo/bar
    extra_opts: ['--strip-components=1', '--show-stored-names']
```

The `show-stored-names` option, available since Ansible 2.1, will [fix the idempotency](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2480#issuecomment-257082347) problems.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, but currently it can cause a crash. See this bug report: http://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29657 an intermediate solution would be to untar in the parent directory and then have a `command: mv /foo/bar-version-someFirstLevelFolder/* foo/bar/`

Comment: Tested in the last version, it works. But, unarchive is not idempotent.

Comment: If you know content of your archive and you can risk a bit, you can use `creates: /some/file/that/unpacks` to get some very limited impotence (tried and `ansible-2.9.7-1.fc30.noarch` correctly skips the task if I rerun the playbook).

Comment: If you want to extract only a subset of files (like `tar -xzf file.tar.gz dirname_in_tar/file.xyz` does), you can add the file(s) to `extra_opts` as well, but you need to add them **unstripped**. Example: `extra_opts: [ --strip-components=1, dirname_in_tar/file.xyz ]` will only extract `file.xyz` from the `dirname_in_tar` directory.